# Do we need to check for nefuchos in our matzah today?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, matzah, inspection

[We are not supposed to eat](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/matzah/) matzoh that contains a nefucha (a "swollen" part/air bubble) bigger than a hazelnut. I'm not entirely sure of the reasons, but it is discussed in [Mishna Berura 461:34](https://books.google.de/books?id=aIAynWkX-ggC&pg=PA25&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=461&f=false).

[According to some](http://www.frumtoronto.com/Blogger.asp?BlogCategoryID=2&ShowEntryID=5309), checking one's matzoh for [kefulos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70519/what-does-a-kefula-look-like) and nefuchos is part of the standard preparation for Pesach.

However, [this](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/default.aspx?pageid=matzah) page indicates that we do not need to check matzah for nefuchos anymore because of the texture of matzoh today. In addition, [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.shulcloud.com/376/uploads/Shabbat_Announcements_July_1_2015_on/Vaad%20Harabanim%20of%20GW%20Pesach%20Bulletin%204.1%20web%20version.pdf) document suggests that commercial matzah may in any case be checked by the bakery for nefuchos and kefulos prior to giving a hechsher.

However, [other sources](http://www.frumtoronto.com/Blogger.asp?BlogCategoryID=2&ShowEntryID=5309) I've seen suggest that we do still need to check our matzah for nefuchos. I would especially wonder about the need to do so for handmade/shmura matzah, which does not have the thin, cracker-like texture of factory matzah.

So, what's the deal? Do we need to check for nefuchos in our factory matzoh? Handmade matzoh? How can we know if the bakery has done it for us?

Comment: "handmade/shmura matzah, which does not have the thin, cracker-like texture of factory matzah": it does in my experience. For what it's worth, I can assure you that at least some people *do* check for folds and bubbles. That doesn't, of course, answer your question as to whether it's necessary.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, you're right, I suppose it's thinner than factory matzoh! Don't know where they get cracker-like though

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56862/questions-regarding-hand-shmurah-matzoh-checking-process?rq=1

Comment: I don't think it's so clear cut we are not allowed to eat air bubbles as many poskim consider them not to be chameitz, they are air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [video](https://youtu.be/au3C6skAFbE) says we do need to check

The main thing is not to eat it

From my experience the hashgocho usually takes responsibility to check, (but sometimes they miss some so if you find do not eat)

---

See this answer it answers your question beautifully
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70543/5120

Comment: I asked a rov my question and got essentially the same answer as you give. He said there is no need to check for it before Pesach as it is almost certainly checked as part of the hashgoche. But if you see folds or significant bubbles in the matzah before you eat it, break that part off.  Please note I was referring specifically to handmade shmura matzah which I told him I paid 25 dollars for, so these comments may not apply to factory matzah. He also asked if I was referring to matzah for the seder, and I said I was not.  CYLOR for a personal psak

Comment: @SAH Thank you, (I personally assume that it is almost impossible for machine matzta to have nefuchois...)

Comment: @SAH This video seems to show some checking regarding ‫machine matza at min 9:09 http://youtu.be/pX52jqVOaxI